# Backbone model initialization

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm studying backbone and I'm trying to initialize an object but I get an empty object as a result from console. What am I doing wrong ?

```
Month = Backbone.Model.extend({
    month:"a",
    values:[
        {label:"Total", value:0}, 
        {label:"Expenses", value:0},
        {label:"Profit", value:0}
    ]   
});
var x = new Month();
console.log(x.toJSON())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `Backbone.Model` is a single object, you can't initialize it with an array.

But you can initialize it with a single object like this :

```
Month = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {label:"Total", month:"a", value:0}   
});
var x = new Month();
console.log(x.toJSON())
```

Comment: Oh my how silly of me... Thank you, I will accept in 9 minutes

Answer (score 1):

What you will want to do is set the defaults for that model.

```
Month = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults:{
    month:"a", 
    values:[
        { total: { label:"Total", value:0 }}, 
        { expenses: { label:"Expenses", value:0 }}, 
        { profit: { label:"Profit", value:0 }}, 
    ]
  }
});
```

This will make sure that when the `Month` object is created, it will have in it's attributes those attributes that you have defined in the defaults object. (I've changed the data a little bit, but I think you get the idea from my example).

You can read more in the documentation: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults

> The defaults hash (or function) can be used to specify the default attributes for your model. When creating an instance of the model, any unspecified attributes will be set to their default value.

Comment: 'month' is a predefines default value i think you forgot to include it inside defaults

Comment: @PanagiotisGeorgeRaditsas - oops. yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

> When **creating** an instance of a model, you can pass in the initial
>   values of the attributes, which will be set on the model. If you
>   define an **`initialize`** function, it will be invoked when the model is
>   created.

[Source](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor)

> The **`defaults`** hash (or function) can be used to specify the default
>   attributes for your model. When creating an instance of the model, any
>   unspecified attributes will be set to their default value.

[Source](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-defaults)

Answer (score 0):

```
var Month = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // you put your Model's methods here or override existing Backbone Model methods here
});
var x = new Month({
  // you put the data of the model here
  month:"a",
  values:[
    {label:"Total", value:0}, 
    {label:"Expenses", value:0},
    {label:"Profit", value:0}
  ]
});
console.log(x.toJSON())
```

**UPDATE**
One important point here is that the values array is going to be shared among all instances of this model, because it's being initialized at the file execution time and being references by the `value` attribute. So if you have 2 models and say change the `Expenses` value in the array in model 1, the `Expenses` in model 2 will also be updated. Something like https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model could help deal with deeply nested data.

Comment: This is different from what the OP wants. Here, you are setting values after the instance of the object is created. In the question, the OP asks how to set values of the model and not of it's instance.

Comment: Where does he ask that? He says "I'm trying to initialize an object but I get an empty object" - and I showed how to idiomatically "initialize an object with values". Why do you assume he wants defaults?

Comment: What makes me think that is where the values are placed. They are placed in the definition of the model and not in the instance.